# Can I connect "neo4j browser" to an "aws neptune" instance?

Tags: amazon-neptune, neo4j-browser

I don't think Neptune is supporting websocket. Could the "neo4j browser" use standard https request based communication?

As I was trying to do ":server connect", passing bolt+s://**name**.cluster-**xxx**.**region**.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182 and I got an error message:
"Browser will attempt to open a websocket connection to .."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Neptune has it's own notebook based utility for interacting with the database called the Neptune Workbench.  Workbench can be used either within a Neptune Notebook instance (preferred method - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/graph-notebooks.html) or via the deployment of the Graph Notebook project (https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook).